# No executable found in a released Debian package

Tags: ros, debian, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, thanks for the help!

I tried to release two ROS packages recently. Let's focus on the one called [lyap_control](http://wiki.ros.org/lyap_control). I had my upstream repository, which I built with catkin_make. The package was indexed (per [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdistro/Tutorials/Indexing%20Your%20ROS%20Repository%20for%20Documentation%20Generation)) and then released (per [here](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/FirstTimeRelease#Releasing_Your_Packages)).

To test it post-release, I installed the package with '**sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-lyap-control**'. So far so good. But, when I try to run it with '**rosrun lyap_control controller**', it can't find the package. Tab complete doesn't work for **controller** but it does work with **lyap_control**. So I guess it's finding the package but not the executable.

Browsing the package files in /opt/ros/indigo, there's not much there. There's a msg folder, cmake folder, and package.xml in /share. But no cpp files and no executables, as far as I can tell.

So what do I have to do to get the debian released properly? I would strongly prefer if the user didn't have to clone my repo and build from source.

Thanks!

P.S. my gut feeling is that the catkin work space is in the wrong place. I'm working with Ubuntu 14.04 and Ros-Indigo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204997/no-executable-found-in-a-released-debian-package/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2015-03-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the [CMakeLists.txt](https://bitbucket.org/AndyZe/lyap_control/src/393f318a84a233ead97e10b48f30a2d4113ab925/CMakeLists.txt?at=public) file in your package, you haven't specified any `Install Targets`. Work on [Catkin's tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Optional_Step:_Specifying_Installable_Targets) for doing that, test with `install` option (i.e. `catkin_make install`) to check the specified targets are created in the generated `install` folder. If things go well then release a new version.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-15**:
Just to add to this, you say:

> [..] there's not much there. There's a msg folder, cmake folder, and package.xml in /share. But no cpp files and no executables [..]

Note that typically, pkgs don't install their sources, and binaries go into `lib/PKG_NAME`, not `share/`.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2015-04-17**:
It worked, 130s. Thanks. The only thing I can add for others is to make sure your CMakeLists.txt is in the correct order. It can matter.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2016-11-09**:
1.5 years later... I'm also figuring out that if you want to `catkin_make install` and then test the installation, you need to open a new terminal window and source the installation folder, e.g. `source /home/andy/Desktop/catkin_ws/install/setup.bash`